# Javascript, Mysqli, and PHP Looping

Tags: php, javascript, loops, mysqli

I am working on a site, and I am having to create a PHP loop with Javascript in it. Is this possible? Here is the snippet of code I need looped.

```
<? while($calendar = mysqli_fetch_array($client_get_calendar)) { ?>
{
 title: '<? echo $calendar['event_title'] ?>',
 start: new Date(<? echo date("Y", strtotime($calendar['date_start'])) ?>, <? echo date("m", strtotime($calendar['date_start'])) ?>, <? echo date("d", strtotime($calendar['date_start'])) ?>),
 end: new Date(<? echo date("Y", strtotime($calendar['date_end'])) ?>, <? echo date("m", strtotime($calendar['date_end'])) ?>, <? echo date("d", strtotime($calendar['date_end'])) ?>),
 className: '<? echo $calendar['importance'] ?>'
},
<? } ?>
```

Will this work for what I am trying to accomplish? It gives me an error, but I don't know what is wrong with the code. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What error are you getting?

Comment: Where you get an error in JavaScript or PHP? What the error message says?

Comment: Shouldn't `<?` be `<?php`

Comment: @ChrisCooney, No, that's not necessary.

Comment: I assume this is all wrapped in a pair of `<script>` tags?

Comment: Looks like it's probably a javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be building JSON output for a Javascript object of data.

This would be better achieved with the following.

```
<?php
$calendar = mysqli_fetch_array($client_get_calendar);
echo json_encode($calendar);
?>
```

Modify the array as you like in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON` is good, `JSON` don't kill Arctic Bears. Everytime someone build a Javascript object without JSON an Arctic Bear dies.

```
$rows = array();
while($calendar = mysqli_fetch_array($client_get_calendar)) {
    $nRow = array(
        'title'     => '' /* <= do your tricks here */,
        'start'     => '' /* <= and here  */,
        'end'       => '' /* <= and here  */,
        'className' => '' /* <= and here  */
    );
    // Now append it do rows
    $rows[] = $nRow;
} 
// dat magic
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you get a syntax error at IE.

And you are trying to make a javascript array of object.

In this case, you got an extra comma at the end of the script
and that will cause error on IE.
the solution is just like @IAmNotProcrastinating said, make a json.

so as the answer above, you can save your data and encode it into a json string.

Continue @IAmNotProcrastinating work, instead of direct output:

```
<?php
if(count($row)>0){
    $data = json_encode($row);
}
else{
    $data = json_encode(array());
}
?>
var js_data = <?php echo $data; ?>;
do_something_with_js_data(js_data);
```